# Un-voting-to-close

Tags: support, closing

Is it possible to un-vote to close a question? For example, I recently voted to close a question then I realised I was wrong and that it should be left open. I want to take back my vote. I want to un-vote to close.

Is this possible? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: No, currently you can't do that. [But the ability to undo close votes is planned to change in the future](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183892/151385).

Comment: I'd like to vote to close this question, as it's already been asked on meta.so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been resolved. You can now un-vote-to-close!

Relevant meta.SO link: [Can we have the ability to retract a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-retract-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)

It is also listed among [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) on 2013-07-15.

Comment: user1729: I've added some meta.SO links to your answer, since I think that it might be useful information for some users. I hope you do mind. (If you do not want them there, you can simply rollback/edit.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak No, they're great and they definitely belong. Thanks. (The first question is over four years old - it took them a while to sort this!)

Answer (score 10):

This is currently [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) on meta.SO, as can be seen [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/915/222340) (and [this specific answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183892/151385) linked to by Mad Scientist contains some more information).

So it shouldn't be too long until you will be able to do this.

Comment: Post 10000 on meta!

Answer (score 8):

> Is there anything I can do?

If you voted to close a question as a duplicate and later realized it isn't, you can help others avoid the same mistake by leaving a comment, e.g., "This question looks similar to X but is **not** a duplicate."

Comment: I have already done this :)